# Laravel 5.8 Email with SMTP and Office 365

Tags: laravel, email

I have been trying to send email for password reset but never receive the email.

No error on the page so not sure how to debug it.

Following is my `.env` configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=myUsername
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='From email address'
MAIL_FROM_NAME='Demo App'
```

Now when I reset the password, I get success message but do not receive email.

When I use following piece of code just to test emails, it works fine

```
\Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => 'Password Rest', 'message' => 'Message has the token to reset password'], function ($message)
    {
        $message->from('from email address', 'Scotch.IO');
        $message->to('To email address');
    });
```

I am just testing with `mailtrap` but will be using Office 365 with following configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
```

How do I debug the mail error or resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: do you have mailtrap.io account? test it with your smtp.office365.com and your mail username and password.

Comment: I have mailtrap account and test emails work fine but the password reset emails doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

> When I use following piece of code just to test emails, it works fine

Since the `Mail::send()` works as intended then the mail configuration shouldn't be the issue.

Try to debug by putting some `dd()` before you return the success message and figure out if your password reset mail sending code is even triggered. Then switch to office 365 once you get mailtrap working.

EDIT after OP comments:

It seems like user class might not be set up properly. Please double check that the user class implements `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait as per the warning in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passwords#introduction)

If all else fail you can try overriding the `sendPasswordResetNotification` function as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passwords#password-customization) under the reset email customization header. That function is the actual function being called by `sendResetLinkEmail()`

Comment: I am using the default `SendsPasswordResetEmails` so I am not sure how to debug it from the trait.

Comment: @MikeRoss if that's the case, on whatever controller you're using that implements the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait, try to call `dd($this->broker()->sendResetLink(['email' => 'your@email.com']));` to test if it sends the email correctly. Make sure that a user with that email exists.

Comment: I get `passwords.sent` printed on the page. Which means success but no emails outgoing.

Comment: Got it. I do not have `email` column in `users` table but it's in a separate table and which was causing problem. Solved it.